# Is it correct to say "a continua"?

Tags: meaning

In [this](https://youtu.be/NNnIGh9g6fA?t=651) video, the phrase "a continua" is mentioned several times. Is that correct use of the indefinite article?

Comment: **Continua** is the plural of **continuum** (biological term): *something that changes in character gradually or in very slight stages without any clear dividing points*.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul probably I didn't make myself clear when I asked the question , actually I was wondering why he used the indefinite article "a" before a plural noun.

Comment: @Moha I think he is using the word as if it were singular, so the "a" isn't wrong. As to continuum vs. continua, neither word is very common; as far as I know, there's no established usage of "continua" in a singular sense, so I would call singular "continua" an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People often say 'a phenomena', 'a criteria', 'a media', where purists would insist on phenomenon, criterion, and medium. However, 'a phenomena' has been found as early as 1576, although I would avoid it. I would definitely avoid 'a criteria'. I would not say 'stadia' as the plural of 'stadium', or 'fora' instead of 'forums'. Even pedantry has its limits.

[Confusing Singular & Plural Forms: Phenomenon/Phenomena, Medium/Media](https://blog.esllibrary.com/2013/08/15/confusing-singular-plural-forms-phenomenonphenomena-mediummedia/)

[Criteria - singular or plural](https://jakubmarian.com/criteria-singular-or-plural/)

Comment: Note that phenomena and criteria are Greek and media is Latin, but the same principles apply. Contrast 'an agenda', where the Latin plural ('things to be done') has developed a related meaning in English ('a list of things to be done'). Google Ngrams shows that 'a continua' is used a tiny fraction as often 'a continuum'.

Comment: Also French, but Larousse is careful to specify a singular sense: Agenda: **ensemble de choses** à traiter dans une période donnée ; _Avoir **un** agenda chargé_ (Larousse)